# OSX - what would cause a d.txt file to contain all my Terminal history to appear in my homedir?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, ipython

I was working when I noticed a file in my homedir called `d.txt`. It contained all of my iPython work I'd been doing in the last hour or so. Is this something that my Terminal app did, or something that iPython did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash saves history for you, in a file determined by the environment variable `HISTFILE`. Usually it's set to `$HOME/.bash_history`. What does `echo $HISTFILE` say?

Comment: I checked my bash history and it had no mention of the word `script`, and my Terminal scroll back (set at 100000 lines) didn't appear to have it either :/

Comment: @orokusaki What is $HISTFILE pointing to? Is it set to d.txt? If so, that's where the file came from - bash saving normal history to the file.

Comment: no, it points to `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 2):

you must have typed script d.txt at some point, or the equivalent.  this will record all your commands in the terminal to the file.

Comment: johnshen64 - is it possible for a program to cause this to happen (like iPython)? I'm sure I haven't typed `script` in my shell, and certainly not `script d.txt`.

Comment: yes, a program could capture terminal output or shell histor as rich mentioned and store it in a file. is the file still growing or at least open? if so you can us lsof to find the owner program of the file.

Comment: unfortunately, I deleted the file :( it appeared to have stopped recording input (based on what I saw in the contents) at about 10 minutes before I noticed it.